# Using variable in same class being set by name space in another class python

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

I have 2 python files as below :

A.py

```
var1 = 1
var2 = var1 + 2
```

B.py

```
import A

print(A.var1)
print(A.var2)

A.var1 = 3
print(A.var1)
print(A.var2)
```

Output :

```
1 
3
3
3 --> Why this ?
```

Why does the second print not reflect the changes ? What can  do to fix this ?
I had an understanding that using namespace reflects the changes.

Comment: Once a module is imported it is not evaluated again when you make changes to the local reference to that module

Answer (score 0):

When module A was imported, var1 and var2 where set (1,3). The import will only run once, var2 will stay 3 unless you set it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

A.py

```
var1 = 1
def var2():
    return var1 + 2
```

B.py

```
import A
A.var1 = 2
print(A.var2())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In particular, please don't just add code; also explain it (Is it the fix for OP's code? Why/how does it work?); also note that the OP asked for an explanation "Why does the second print not reflect the changes?" – only stating code doesn't answer that.